# A queuing system which supports job batching (e.g. several jobs for 1 worker at once)

Tags: php, gearman, beanstalkd

I'm looking for a queuing system that could support the following scenario:

- A client adds a job - to check how many Facebook likes a particular url (URL1) has;
- A client adds another job - to check the same information for URL2;
- [....]
- A worker picks up anything from 1 to 50 jobs (urls) from the queue (e.g., if there's only 5 - it picks up 5, if there's 60 - picks up 50, leaving others for another worker), and issues a request against Facebook API (which allows multiple urls per request). If it succeeds, all jobs are taken out of the queue, if it fails - all of them stay.

I'm working with PHP and I've looked into [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/), but did not find any similar functionality. Is there any (free) queuing system that would support such a "batch-dequeuing"?

Or, maybe, anybody could suggest an alternative way of dealing with such an issue? I've considered keeping a list of "to check" urls outside the queuing system and then adding them in bundles of max N items with a cron job that runs every X period. But that's kind of building your own queue, which defeats the whole purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: It's not the cleanest way to do it, but I think that with Beanstalk you can have one worker try to get multiple jobs (just use a loop).

Comment: @trutheality I'll definitely take a look - so far could not find anybody mentioning such a possibility, though :/

Comment: @Aurimas, How did you solve this problem using gearman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Beanstalkd to fetch 100 twitter names at a time, and then calling an API with them all. When I was done, I deleted them - but I could have elected to not delete some (or all) if I wished.

It was a simple loop to reserve the initial 100 (one at a time), and I put the results (the job ID and the data returned) into an array. When I was done dealing with the payload (in this instance, a twitter screen-name), I went through deleting them - but I could have easily have released them back into the queue.

Comment: Thanks - I see how you can do it with Beanstalkd. I went with Gearman in the end, so now I just need to figure out if I can do the same with Gearman.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take inspiration from [MediaWiki's job queue system](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aJob_queue). Not very complicated, but it does have [some issues](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Job_queue_redesign) that you may run into if you decide to roll your own.

The DB tables used for this are defined [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aJob_table).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't really think that this queue system supports what I am looking for, either (unless I missed it). It's a good starting point for developing own queue system, nevertheless!